# Avoid the creation of multiple Jupyter kernels for each virtualenv

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, virtualenv

I am working with Jupyter Notebooks and several virtualenvs in Ubuntu 18.04 (I'm not using Conda).

I usually create a new virtualenv for each new python project I'm working on and since I'm working on many projects I would like to AVOID the creation of multiple Jupyter kernels as suggested [here](https://anbasile.github.io/posts/2017-06-25-jupyter-venv/).

Instead, I would like to tell Jupyter to start the python kernels in the virtualenv in which I am running it BY DEFAULT.

I know this is possible since it is the way it used to work, but then I don't know what I did wrong and now if I don't create a kernel for each virtualenv Jupyter doesn't allow me to use the python modules I have installed in that environment.

The way it used to work was the following:

- I activate the virtualenv

  > source bin/activate
- I installed Jupyter in that virtualenv
- I ran Jupyter in that virtualenv

  > jupyter notebook
- I selected Python3/2, R kernel depending on what I needed
- I could import all the modules installed in that virtualenv

Now it's not working anymore and if I try to import a module installed in that virtualenv it gives me the following error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'modulename'

Even if I checked that the Jupyter notebook it's looking in the right paths:

```
! which python
/home/user/venv_name/bin/python
```

and

```
! which pip
/home/user/venv_name/bin/pip
```

How can I bring back the old setting?

Comment: Can you try `import sys; sys.path` both on python interpreter and on jupyter cell and see if you have a difference?  If so, a workaround is to append paths at the beginning of the notebook.  I am looking for a better solution on my own, though.